# WP_Comment_Query - Get comments and answers separately

Tags: theme-development, themes, comments

I was developing a theme and this time I chose to use the bootstrap4, I found some difficulties in the way but I managed to solve them and the result was satisfactory, however creating my comments.php I noticed that wordpress does not differentiate comments from answers, for example:

[image: c_and_a]

So how do I get the comments and answers separately? I would like to pick up the answers separately to be able to add further below your respective comments.

comments.php

```
<!--    Comentarios    -->
<asside class="comments-area container">

    <?php if(have_comments()) : ?>

    <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">

        <h3 class="mb-4">Comentários</h3>
        <?php 

            $comment_args = array(
                'order'    =>    'DEC'
            );

            $comment_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
            $comment = $comment_query->query($comment_args);

            foreach($comment as $comment) :
        ?>
        <!--    comentario    -->
        <div class="blog-comment row mb-2">
            <div class="comment-avatar col-md-1 pr-1">
                <img class="mx-auto rounded-circle img-fluid" src="<?php echo get_avatar_url($comment->comment_author_email ); ?>" alt="avatar"/>
            </div>
            <div class="comment-content col-md-11">
                <h6 class="comment-meta small">Por <?php echo $comment->comment_author; ?> em <?php echo comment_date('d-m-Y'); ?></h6>
                <div class="comment-body">
                    <p>
                        <?php echo $comment->comment_content; ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </div>

    <?php endif; ?>

</asside>
```

Comment: What's an "answer"? WordPress doesn't have the concept of an "answer" as distinct from a comment. Are you using a plugin?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I think the term would be reply, I used google translator for this post so I think he translated literally